# After refresh PrintControl looses margins

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, printing

At app starting, the print control generates OK with 25.4mm margins (on all sides), but after refresh it changes to 5.08mm.

I use a control named [Print Bar](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13982/Print-Preview-Control-Bar). The below code does not work.

The BeginPrint and PrintPage method: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72715388/add-qr-codes-in-columns-in-print-preview/72718695#72718695)

Print before

[image: Print before] [image: Print After]

Can I force somehow the margins?

My refresh code is:

```
    private void setupReport()
    {
        PaperSize ps = new PaperSize();
        ps.RawKind = 9;
        printDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps;
        printDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        ////printDocument1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = ;

        this.preview = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintPreviewControl();
        this.preview.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;

        this.preview.Document = this.printDocument1;

        this.preview.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 42);
        this.preview.Name = "printPreviewControl1";
        this.preview.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(786, 362);
        this.preview.TabIndex = 2;

        this.ucPrintBar1.PreviewControl = this.preview;
        this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(this.preview);
        this.ucPrintBar1.loadDefaults();
        
    }
```

Comment: Hi Molnar Istvan, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. 
It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the following five lines to `setupReport()` method's first line:

```
private void setupReport()
{
    this.ucFormManagement1.addExtra("LeftMargin",printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left);
    this.ucFormManagement1.addExtra("RightMargin", printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right);
    this.ucFormManagement1.addExtra("BottomMargin", printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom);
    this.ucFormManagement1.addExtra("TopMargin", printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top);
    this.ucFormManagement1.addExtra("Orientation", printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape);

    this.preview = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintPreviewControl();
    this.preview.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;

    this.preview.Document = this.printDocument1;

    this.preview.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 42);
    this.preview.Name = "printPreviewControl1";
    this.preview.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(786, 362);
    this.preview.TabIndex = 2;

    this.ucPrintBar1.PreviewControl = this.preview;
    this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(this.preview);
    this.ucPrintBar1.loadDefaults(); 
}
```

Now the print refresh works like it should.